# Mapping Content Controls in Quick Parts

Tags: xml, ms-word, xsd

I have this set of boiler templated verbiage that has a lot of repeating areas. I have made Content Controls so that I can map repeating areas to each other. I saved it within a specific document so anytime I go to that document and fill in the initial unique form fields it will update all their duplicates.

The issue that I am having is that when I save it as a quick part the Content Controls are no longer mapped. I want to be able to not have to open that specific document to use that verbiage sometimes. So my idea was to map all of the verbiage then save it as a quick part. I even tried saving the document that has the initial verbiage as a template to load into my open documents but it doesn't help.

Does anyone know a work around that allows me to save a set of verbiage to a Quick Part and to still have mapped content controls that automatically update the copied content controls in different locations?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mapping-content-controls-and-saving-in-quick-parts/86a96ea4-99db-4696-aa9f-07c18201dbc1. Please read A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Your post title refers to both Content Controls and Formfields. Content Controls were not designed to be used in documents containing Formfields and trying to do so is a known source of problems for end-users. Formfields also don't work unless your document has 'filling in forms' protection applied - which isn't needed for Content Controls to work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: DId you create your own Custom XML Parts using VBA? If so, you *should* be able to save a copy of the document where you created those parts *as a .dotx" As long as you base each new

Answer (score 0):

### You can *repurpose* the already built-in Mapped Document Property Content Controls

*This is a limited solution as discussed at the bottom of the answer. It does not require macros and will work in any Windows version of Word beginning with Word 2007.*

I am assuming that you want these in [Global Template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) rather than in a document template. You would do this in your [Global Template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) that holds the Quick Parts (or other custom Building Blocks). *See below under **Explanation** for more about how to do this in a document template, which is easier.*

This gives them different Prompt Text and titles in your template.

Then save those repurposed controls as Quick Parts in your template. Once your template is loaded as a global template, these will be available to all documents/templates.

Here is a [temporary link to a .dotx template](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vfmazpl93zr82yjsxs59b/Document-Property-Repurpose.dotx?rlkey=eu1qkzre3qxh9kwdlb9qahajp&dl=0) which can be used as a [Global Template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) to demonstrate the principle. If loaded as a Global Template, it gives access to three mapped content controls.

[image: Screenshot of Quick Parts with added parts]

Here is a link to my page on [Repurposing the Document Property Content Controls](https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart). Here is a link to a [video on this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAskwzL7zbI) by Laura Townsend.

Here are my related Answers in SuperUser:

- [Is there a way to make two parts of the document linked? So that if I change one part of the document the other automatically updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/1706812/is-there-a-way-to-make-two-parts-of-the-document-linked-so-that-if-i-change-one/1706847#1706847)
- [Customize existing MS Word Template document's variables & Content Controls](https://superuser.com/questions/1708574/customize-existing-ms-word-template-documents-variables-content-controls)

These discuss more about repeating data and Content Controls.

**There are two primary limits to this process.**

1. The Content Controls under Document Properties are all plain text except for the Publish Date control which is a Date Picker.
2. There are only 15 of these controls.

SharePoint allows adding more Document Property Content Controls but this answer is designed for off-the-shelf Word. There are problems with templates in SharePoint as well.

### Explanation

The thing is, the xml mapping structure does not get saved in a Quick Part or other Building Block.

You do not need to do this for a **document template**. If this is a document template then the new document based on the template will have the mapping as part of its structure inherited from the template. Your mapped controls can be saved as Quick Parts in that template and will work in all documents created from the template. The Quick Parts will only be available in documents created from the template while the documents remain *attached* to the document template. Once placed in the document, they will continue to work in the document but the Quick Parts will not be available if the template is not the attached template.

Here are temporary links to a [document template](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xavirt2tpnxrydo4hsnmj/Mapped-Content-Controls-in-Quick-Parts.dotx?rlkey=c3r8x3xyk12u4d43ibdgz9zel&dl=0) containing mapped Controls saved in Quick Parts and a [document based on that template](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/99zl76gyk9urcfohm4qg2/deleteme-Content-Controls-Quick-Parts.docx?rlkey=n6nuauq91gd4omyfykvc4j1xa&dl=0). When a document is created based on the template, the Quick Parts are available. If they are inserted in the document, they will remain mapped even if the Quick Parts become unavailable because the document is no longer attached to the template holding the Quick Parts. The mapping continues to be active in the document.

However, in a [Global Template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global), that xml structure is not available to other documents. We use nodes already mapped by Word in every document.

The [Global Template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) must be loaded by any user.

What this does is borrow or repurpose the mapping that is built into Word for these Document Property Content Controls. One attaches a new name and gives a new purpose to the control. When that control is copied or saved as a Quick Part/Building Block the name is also repeated. When any instance is changed in a document, the underlying mapped node is changed and it gets updated in any instances of the control in the document.